# Add/delete old rows dynamically using hooks reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning to use hooks with react and trying to make a simple website where you write 2 values and add them to a list. Each item in the list got a delete button.

For some reason, when I am adding more than 2 rows the problem seems to start. If I for example add 2 rows, and press delete on the old rows that got loaded on start - it is either deleting them or replacing them with same values as the new rows.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here since the delete works until I add more than +2 rows directly at the start.

Kinda hard to explain, but I've made a sandbox where it's easier to see the problem.

Delete & add functions:

```
  const deleteRow = async (index, e) => {
    var data = testArr;
    data.splice(index, 1);

    setTestArr([...data]);
  };

  const addRow = async e => {
    var obj = {
      id: 1,
      start: inputFrom,
      stop: inputTo
    };

    var data = testArr;
    data.push(obj);

    setTestArr([...data]);
  };
```

Mapping function:

```
{testArr.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={item.id} className="col-12">
          <div className="control-group mb-1">
            <span className="mr-2">
              {item.start} - {item.stop}
            </span>
            <input
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-light"
              value="Delete row"
              onClick={e => deleteRow(index, e)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Sandbox:

[image: Edit creact-hooks-usestate-nk4cl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you might not use `var` keyword and instead use ES `const` || `let`, for making sure you are not encountering unexpected side effects  because of JS hoisting,

second -

```
var data = testArr;
data.splice(index, 1);
```

is illegal move, cause `data` isn't a different place in memory from the state, it is just a pointer on it, and therefore you modify state outside `setState`

the first option is to shallow copy state

```
let data = [...testArr];
```

or directly implement the logic inside `setState`

```
// delete
setTestArr(prev => prev.filter((item, i) => i != index ));
// add
setTestArr(prev => [...prev, obj]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with these functions:

```
const deleteRow = async (index, e) => {
  var data = [...testArr];
  data.splice(index, 1);
  setTestArr(data);
};
```

and

```
const addRow = async e => {
  setTestArr([{
   id: 1,
   start: inputFrom,
   stop: inputTo
 },...testArr]);
};
```

I sugest you tu use useCallback t define these.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this delete function:

```
  const deleteRow = (index, e) => {
    setTestArr(prev => {
      
      return prev.filter((e, i) => i !== index);
    });
  };
```

Instead of mutating the data, just filtering out, the index what we dont needed.